# Workaround to submit app to app store with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, swift2, xcode7

When trying to submit an app compiled with Xcode 7 to iTunes Connect for review, I get an error message

> Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK.

[image]

Is there any workaround to this? I've already updated all of my code to Swift 2.0, and I would like to not have to convert it all back to Swift 1.2 to upload it.

Setting the `Deployment Target` to `iOS 8.0` doesn't work, either

[image]

Are there any ways that I can compile the Swift 2.0 code in a way that would allow me to upload it to iTunes Connect (maybe something in the `Build Settings`), or do I have to convert all of the code back to Swift 1.2?

Comment: If you want to submit now, you'll have to use Xcode 6.4. Apple checks what you try to send and they won't allow anything from beta versions right now. So unfortunately you will have to wait or convert to 1.2

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You should probably put that in an answer as opposed to a comment.

Comment: Just remember one simple rule - Any beta Xcode == Never submit to App Store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow submitting anything using beta stage tools. They check all submissions so there is no reasonable way to submit anything done with Swift 2.0. Your only options are either to wait until Xcode 7 is officially out or convert to Swift 1.2.

Comment: [Let the pain begin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTrBV.png). Make sure to save a backup of your old Swift code before you convert it - don't learn the hard way like I just did

Comment: @Jojodmo you shouldn't code without version control (like git) in the first place imo.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few days ago Apple started accepting apps that are built with [Xcode 7 GM](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/). Here is a reference from Apple themselves https://developer.apple.com/news/

I ran into a lot of build errors with iOS 9 as there are some breaking changes and new settings for the latest devices. I combined all the errors and their fixes on my blog post. It is targeted at Ionic users, but a lot of the issues are general and any iOS developer could encounter them. http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/ios9-and-ionic-build-warnings/