# App Store Team error saying "your app contains bitcode" after application submission

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I've never heard of this term `bitcode` before at all and I don't even know where to start looking around on how to fix this issue.

I am using `Xcode 7 beta 3` and I've successfully uploaded my app 3 times but every time I upload it, it would change the status to  `invalid binary`

I got an email from the App Store Team saying this

> "Invalid Executable - The executable 'ESUHSD.app/ESUHSD' contains
>   bitcode."

I don't know what information you need to know about the app so I was hoping any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some info here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2

Comment: I'm curious about this solution. I think that apps are supposed to contain bitcode

Comment: The fact that you are uploading an app to the app store using `xcode 7 beta 3` is your issue. You can't upload apps using beta versions of `xcode`

Comment: So you have _not_ uploaded it successfully, right? Xcode 7 is beta. It's not accepted until Xcode 7 is released.

Comment: @Cyril Ivar Garcia: Did you actually successfully upload using the beta version?  I see that the accepted answer implies you did, so there are several (possibly) erroneous posts floating around...

Comment: Also, are you intending for release, or beta testing... Thanks...

Comment: @rholmes yes my intention was to submit for beta testing using test flight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you can submit **any release apps** built with with a beta version of Xcode (even if you target an existing iOS / WatchKit SDK combination).

As far as "bitcode", go to the developer.apple.com and take a peek at WWDC videos on "app thinning", as well as the relevant documentation for the next release.

For submitting an app for beta testing, that is another story. In general, that's possible, but there may be some quirks; the answer by @Jan covers the specifics for Xcode 7 beta having to do with bitcode.

**For references saying not to submit release apps to the AppStore with beta Xcode versions, see the following posts** (If you come up with definitive docs from Apple, it would be great to add a link):

From the Apple Developer forums, the accepted answer is that you never can submit using beta Xcode, and multiple people state that you've never been allowed to submit using beta software.  There is one section where it mentions a workaround regarding bitcode and submissions, but it was suggested this was for AFTER Xcode 7 was released formally:  [Apple Forum: Can you submit to the App Store an app built with Xcode 7 as long as you are not targeting iOS 9?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3653)

From StackOverflow: The accepted answer concurs that submitting apps using beta Xcode is forbidden: [Workaround to submit app to app store with Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361233/workaround-to-submit-app-to-app-store-with-xcode-7)

From StackOverflow: "App needs to be compiled with release version of Xcode" is the accepted answer: [Submitting iOS app using beta version of xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443583/submitting-ios-app-using-beta-version-of-xcode)

Additionally, the Apple technical document on submitting to the App Store says you should use the latest Xcode and SDK -- they don't mention beta vs. release, but the link to the "latest" goes to the latest **release** version of Xcode, available via the Mac App Store.  See [Technical Q&A QA1806: What version of Xcode and SDK should I be using when building for the App Store?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1806/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013838)

NOTE: Edited based on OP's stated intent in comment for beta testing, not release build to prior SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can still submit to AppStore if you want. At least I had to for Beta Testing. You just need to disable Bitcode inside the Build Settings:

[image]

That will get rid of the warnings until the AppStore is ready for Bitcode.

Keep in mind though, that you cannot invite External Users to test the app if you submit with Xcode 7. Only Internal Users can test it.

Comment: Ok so I see you can submit for beta testing with the beta Xcode, but not release?  Thanks for clarifying!